# LTE stack protocol development

Tags: stack, protocols, lte

While reading an article on LTE, I came across  a term "LTE Stack Protocol Development". Sadly, there was no further explanation on the term and when I looked it up on google, it turned up all job openings in LTE protocol development.

So here is the question, what exactly is "LTE stack protocol development" and if possible I would like to learn more about it, could some one point me to some good reading material, it could be a book or website.

Basically, I would like to know "what and how" part for this. By "what" I mean, what all would be required to learn this development and by "how" I would like to know how it can be done/learnt or how it defers from product/application development in industry.

Thanks for your time to go through my question and I apologize if I sound too demanding in the question :).

Answer (score 3):

Look up [Protocol Stack on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_stack) for a discussion of the basic concepts of a protocol stack.  Also see the OSI model, which is a standard example.

LTE is a system defined by 3GPP, which is an international partnership of interested companies.  There are diagrams of the LTE protocol stack [here.](http://lteworld.org/lte-protocols-specifications)

LTE protocols are divided into two sets: the Control Plane, which deals with what you can call "administrative tasks" like registering a phone on the network, tracking its location and setting up a data session.  The User Plane contains the protocols that actually carry user data.

The website to which I linked is particularly useful because you can click on the names of each protocol to get links to its formal specification document on the [3GPP website.](http://www.3gpp.org)

To relate the LTE protocol stack roughly to the simple model given on the Wikipedia protocol stack page, look for IP, which corresponds to the Internet layer.  Everything below IP corresponds to the LTE protocols for the data link and physical layers.

On Google, you can find books about LTE, which will give you a summary of the 3GPP specifications.  These are useful for gaining an overall understanding.  Protocol stack development is the process of creating these protocols in code.  To do this, you must study the official 3GPP specifications themselves, which you can download from the website.

Comment: Thanks for the links, they were quite useful. So from what I understand, first I need to have in depth knowledge of TCP/IP stack and how it is implemented using C language, from there I will need to read 3GPP specs to understand LTE stack development, right?

Comment: Most people pick up this knowledge on the job.  I would start by reading a book about LTE (look at reviews on Amazon).  There is plenty of information to get an overview of TCP and IP on the internet, and books as well of course.  3GPP specs are very detailed, and also huge - you can't read them all.  What you can do, is learn your way around the 3GPP website.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily C, depends where you are going to use this. If it is terminal testing / simulator likes the ones of rhode and schwarz, qualcomm, better off with C++. You need to implement the specs on system level, then it is harware teams job to do the RTL syntehsis and bring it at the hardware level.

As a stack level implementation, is more like software development, if you go below the stack at physical layer, then comes more of an engineering perspective, dealing most things at hardware level.

So be good with C++, a degree in communication systems, electrical engineering, CS focus in Communications etc should be the preferable choice and go through some book related to LTE

Comment: PHY/MAC/RLC/RRC layer you should understand well, at the end of the day, it is programming, implementing some protocol only difference is protocol is very intensive and big.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are looking for this 
http://www.queryhome.com/27610/protocol-architecture-of-lte-network

Answer (score 0):

Telecom protocols are usually designed using SDL translated from specifications approved by specification committees. The SDL is converted to ASN.1 scripts and loaded in to case tools. The tools generate c code for a specific platform and compiler. A protocol design house usually have a asn.1 stack of the technology that acts as simulator and asn.1 for new protocol stacks.

Answer (score 0):

By "what" I mean, what all would be required to learn this development

> Its a big thing to learn the whole LTE protocol stack development and companies have big teams dedicated for this. I will suggest to pick a layer/module and then study the specific of that layer to be able to do anything meaningful.
>   www.3GPP.org is the site that everyone refers but its very cumbersome.
>   You can try www.sharedtechnote.com which is written by an engineer and is a good source for Access Stratum aspect of protocol stack.

by "how" I would like to know how it can be done/learnt or how it defers from product/application development in industry.

> If you want to see an open source implementation you can goto https://github.com/srsLTE/srsLTE to get an idea about protocol stack development.

As others have mentioned its a big topic to go after "LTE Stack Protocol Development". I will suggest to go and compare the LTE protocol stack with OSI model and then pick and choose one layer e.g. Radio Resource Control(RRC),Radio Link Control(RLC) or MAC layer and then study more about it. Look for 3GPP specification for the same e.g. I will google "3GPP spec RLC" and then go and download relevant spec. Complex to begin but after getting basics right you will be able to develop something meaningful.