# protocols in long term evolution(LTE). 4G

Tags: protocols, lte

4G-Lte consists of different layers protocol stack. I have Understand the graph of that stack. One thing i didn't get, are they are protocols or just a layers.If they are protocols, Can i get open Source code for each protocols in C.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16421955/lte-stack-protocol-development and http://www.eventhelix.com/lte/lte-tutorials.htm#.UjG3CH_QpNg are good places to start reading. There exists open source stacks for alot of different protocols used for LTE signalling.

Answer (score 2):

I guess by "layers" you mean the PDCP,RLC,MAC,NAS,RRC that you see in the LTE user plane/control plane protocol stacks. Yes, they are protocols between a UE(User Equipment) and the LTE network (eNB, MME, etc), and there are protocol specifications defined for each one in 3GPP. For example, the RRC is defined in 36.331, RLC in 36.322. 
I think for some simpler protocols like PDCP or RLC, you can find some open source codings. However, for more complicated protocols like RRC, NAS or MAC, I haven't seen open source.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, LTE is a whole system (or stack). It is devide into different functions, we call it layer. The way layer designed we call it protocol. Protocol is mapped into layer.

SO. NAS, RRC, PDCP, RLC, MAC, PHY is both layer and protocol. Just as Alex Wang sayed, you can find protocol specifications in 3GPP.

And you can find open source code. BUT the quality is not so good.

As references：

http://www.openairinterface.org/

http://openlte.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you will not obtain C open source code for the protocol stack. There are companies out there that sells you c code (for amazing amounts of money) but they were derived from the SDL diagrams derived from the specs ran through a casetool to generate the C code.

There are ways around this though, by converting the SDL sequences mentioned in the specs and implementing them in a sequential design on a functional programming environment like haskel or erlang. Actually this how manufacturers of network equipment does it.

Answer (score 0):

A protocol stack is a set of protocol layers. The design is such that they are layers with protocols for inter-working between layers / network entities.

The challenge in finding such tools is because LTE standards are evolving very fast and hence it would substantial effort to maintain it inline with the changes for complicated layers.